# Can't forward emails using rules in Mail.app

Tags: mail.app, mail-rules

None of my Mail.app rules seem to be working to forward any emails even though they are working normally for other things: moving into folders, marking as read, etc. I'm using macOS Big Sur Version 11.6.2.

Here's an example of a simple test rule that isn't working:

[image]

When I receive a test email with that wording in the subject, nothing seems to happen. The email lands in my inbox but I don't see anything that indicates anything was forwarded, in the sent folder or otherwise. This seems to be the same behavior as found on [this unresolved Apple discussions thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8177694).

Here's what I've tried to resolve this so far:

1. Varied **any** and **all** in the if statement.
2. [Used **Redirect Message** instead of **Forward Message**.](https://talk.macpowerusers.com/t/mail-rule-to-forward-redirect-isnt-working-anyone-successful-with-forwarding/7351/3)
3. [Added in an **Every message** condition.](https://superuser.com/a/874890/395846)
4. [Made sure there there were no **Stop evaluating rules** actions before this rule](https://superuser.com/a/232944/395846) (by making it the first rule).

None of the above works. How to get it working?